# Why am I getting an unexpected token error when running a test on my JavaScript code in CodeWars Kata creation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set up a new Kata for CodeWars. 
This code works in a browser (IE and Chrome).

When I run the test on a solution to my code in the CodeWars Kata setup page, I get an unexpected token error when I try to validate my solution to the Kata.

I am not familiar with Node JS; but,  I think the error is a Node JS error. 
This is my first try at writing/setting up a Kata. I did read a some of the tutorial pages.

The error appears to be pointing at either the end of the forEach statement or the end of the map statement. I checked all the brackets and parens. I think I have everything I need otherwise, it wouldn't run in a browser, right? 
(Did I nest the forEach statement correctly inside the map statement?)
I have tried taking things out and running the code.

Here is

- the error,
- a list of my code with test data,
- and an explanation of the Kata and how one should code a solution:

Here is the error I am getting:

> [eval]:59
>               });
>                ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
>       at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>       at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
>       at 
>       at evalScript (bootstrap_node.js:353:27)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:122:11)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.j

Here is my code with test data at the end:

```
<script>

function birdCode(arr){

var matchArr = [];
var str = "";

var arrReturn = arr.map(function(item){
    str = "";
    item = item.replace("-", " ").toUpperCase();

    if(/ /.test(item) === false){ // Name with one word.
        return item.slice(0, 4);
    }
    else if(item.match(/ /g).length === 1){ // Name with two words.
        matchArr = item.match(/ [A-Z]{2}/); 
        str = matchArr.join("");
        return item.slice(0, 2) + str.replace(" ", "");
    }
    else if(item.match(/ /g).length === 2){ // Name with three words.
        var arrName = item.split(" ");
        arrName.forEach(function(item, idx){
            if(idx === 2){
                    str = str + item.slice(0, 2);
            }
            else{
                str = str + item.slice(0, 1);
            }
        }); 
        return str;
    }
    else if(item.match(/ /g).length === 3){ // Name with four words.
        matchArr = item.match(/ [A-Z]{1}/g);
        str = item.slice(0, 1) + matchArr.join("");
        return str.replace(/ /g, "");       
    }
});

console.log("arrReturn: " + arrReturn);

return arrReturn;

}

birdCode(["American Redstart", "Northern Cardinal", "Pine Grosbeak", "Barred Owl", "Starling", "Cooper's Hawk", "Pigeon"]);
birdCode(["Great Crested Flycatcher", "Bobolink", "American White Pelican", "Red-Tailed Hawk", "Eastern Screech Owl", "Blue Jay"]);
birdCode(["Black-Crowned Night Heron", "Northern Mockingbird", "Eastern Meadowlark", "Dark-Eyed Junco", "Red-Bellied Woodpecker"]);
birdCode(["Scarlet Tanager", "Great Blue Heron", "Eastern Phoebe", "American Black Duck", "Mallard", "Canvasback", "Merlin", "Ovenbird"]);
birdCode(["Fox Sparrow", "White-Winged Crossbill", "Veery", "American Coot", "Sora", "Northern Rough-Winged Swallow", "Purple Martin"]);
```

> You will be given an array of common American birds. You are to create
>   a function to convert these to the four-letter codes used by birders
>   and websites like eBird (created by the Cornell Lab of Ornithology and
>   the Audubon Society).
>
> Rules:
>
> If a given name in the input array is one word, return the first four
>   letters of the name as the code.
>
> If the name is two words, return the first two letters of each word.
>
> If the name is three words, return the first two letters of the first
>   two words and the first two letters of the third word.
>
> If the name is four words long, return the first letters of all four
>   words.
>
> (These are some of the rules of the actual process used to create
>   codes by the organizations mentioned above.)
>
> The returned codes should be in an array. They should be in the order
>   in which they were given. The four letters in the returned codes
>   should all be in UPPER CASE.
>
> Hyphen/dashes should be treated as spaces in a given bird name.
>
> Note: No bad data will be given.
>
> For example:
>
> If you are given an array with these two values: "Herring Gull" and
>   "Black-Capped Chickadee"
>
> You should return these two values: "HEGU" and "BCCH"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Well, this probably means something...

I changed the code. I took out the forEach and the map. I used for loops instead. 
And, I am still getting that error even though the code does not have "});" in it anywhere.

```
function birdCode(arr){

var matchArr = [];
var str = "";
var arrReturn = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    str = "";
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace("-", " ").toUpperCase();

    if(/\s/.test(arr[i]) === false){ // Name with one word.
        arrReturn.push(arr[i].slice(0, 4));
    }
    else if(arr[i].match(/\s/g).length === 1){ // Name with two words.
        matchArr = arr[i].match(/\s[A-Z]{2}/); 
        str = matchArr.join("");
        arrReturn.push(arr[i].slice(0, 2) + str.replace(" ", ""));
    }
    else if(arr[i].match(/\s/g).length === 2){ // Name with three words.
        var arrName = arr[i].split(" ");
        var nameBuild = "";
        for(var j = 0; j < arrName.length; j++){
            if(j === 2){
                str = str + arrName[j].slice(0, 2);
            }
            else{
                str = str + arrName[j].slice(0, 1);
            }   
        nameBuild = nameBuild + str;
        str = "";       
        }
        arrReturn.push(nameBuild);
    }
    else if(arr[i].match(/\s/g).length === 3){ // Name with four words.
        matchArr = arr[i].match(/ [A-Z]{1}/g);
        str = arr[i].slice(0, 1) + matchArr.join("");
        arrReturn.push(str.replace(/\s/g, ""));     
    }

}

// console.log("arrReturn: " + arrReturn);

return arrReturn;
```

Comment: Your code seems to run just fine in node... ([try here](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground), for example).

Comment: Also runs in jsfiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/dj4rqsk1/

Comment: Can you remove the `<script>` tag if you also added it to the editor ?

Comment: It runs fine in Edabit. But, I wanted to add it to CodeWars, too.

Comment: Taha Paksu: I just checked the code in the CodeWars window. It starts with "function birdCode(arr){" and ended with "return arrReturn;"

Comment: See added notes and code. Maybe it is something on the CodeWars' servers?

Comment: I am going to file a CodeWars bug report.